# Is it better to do multiple SQL commits or a single commit followed by another call?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using SQL Alchemy with a SQL database and have a best practice question. I need to insert a list of objects into SQL, and then return them to the front end with the SQL-generated IDs. However I can only access those IDs after the commit. Right now I loop through the list and add an object on each iteration, and then commit once they've all been added. But that way I don't have the IDs.

Would it be better to commit after each loop iteration, and get the IDs that way, or to bulk commit the new entries after the loop ends, and then make another call to get the new entries with their IDs?

Comment: Unless you are dealing with a remarkable number of records, I think it really doesn't matter much.  Often an application simply relies on "auto-commit" behavior surrounding various operations ... doing each operation in its own single transaction.  But it's also okay to commit the records, commit, and then re-query *(if you're certain you know how to write that re-query so as to get the right rows)* to find the IDs.  (You should also do that re-query in a transaction.)

Comment: Assuming you're using a DBMS that supports `INSERT ... RETURNING ...`, you should be able to get the generated IDs as part of the insertion query. If you're using sqlalchemy ORM, this should be happening automatically for you - your entities should have their ID properties updated as soon as they are flushed. If you're using sqlalchemy core, you can use the `returning=` option of the `insert()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your data schema, your database, and how many records you're inserting. For example, results with SQLite are going to be different from PostgreSQL because SQLite wasn't built for concurrency.

I'm using it with SQLite, multiprocessing using 7 out of 8 cores, and about 10,000 records. In my specific case, committing just once at the very end took 5.5 minutes. Committing for each record is taking far longer. 45 minutes has passed and it's still not finished. That's a 9x performance difference.

If you're using a database with concurrency in mind like Postgres, I don't think the performance difference would be as great, but it looks like less commits improves performance.